# 'Failed to execute MI command: -exec-run' error when trying to debug a GNU project with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, gnu

I wish to debug GNU Emacs in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ on my macOS Sierra. I have downloaded the source code with Git and built the project successfully via the command line. I then imported the project to Eclipse as an existing Makefile project with the GNU autotools toolchain setting.

I can now run the Emacs GUI from Eclipse. However, when I try to debug it (with gdb), I get the following error message:

```
'Launching emacs-26.0.50.1' has encountered a problem.

Error in final launch sequence

Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
During startup program terminated with signal ?, Unknown signal.
During startup program terminated with signal ?, Unknown signal.
```

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get rid of this error by specifying the *full* path to the `.gdbinit` file in the `Run > Debug Configurations... > C/C++ Application > emacs-26.0.50.1 > Debugger > GDB command file:` textbox.

I now get a different error, but this is a matter for another question...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message while using the debugger for a small dummy code. I used the suggestion given in [this link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_choose_another_debugger_integration_for_CDT.3F) and got it fixed. In short, I had to change the debugger to an older one. Hope that helps if you are still having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I've become so frustrated with Eclipse that I ditched it and switched to NetBeans instead, which works great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was using USB 3.0 port. Connected board to USB 2 port and it was working fine.